# Subscribe to a users My Matters via SDK

Tags: sdk, autonomy, imanage

Using Autonomy WorkSite 8.5 SP2 SDK, I am attempting to programmicaly add a shortcut to another users My Matters which I have been told can be done by first subscribing to the other users My Matters, add the shortcut then unsubscribe.

I am therefore attempting to subscribe to another users My Matters however I am having issues with how to subscribe, with the below code I am able to locate the user's My Matters:

```
Dim objSFSP As IManSubscriptionFolderSearchParameters = oDms.CreateSubscriptionFolderSearchParameters
objSFSP.Add( imFolderAttributeID.imFolderOwner, sShortcutUser )
Dim objFolders As IManFolders = oMatters.FindRootSubscriptionFoldersNotSubscribedTo(oDatabaseList, objSFSP)
```

And from reading the COM Reference guide I should be able to subscribe to a users My Matters with the following code:

```
Dim objWorkArea As IManWorkArea = oSess.WorkArea
Dim oFolderShortcuts As IManSubscriptionFolderShortcuts = objWorkArea.SubscriptionFolder.SubFolders
Dim oFolderShortcut As IManFolderShortcut = oFolderShortcuts.AddNewSubscriptionFolderShortcutInheriting(objFolders)
```

The problem I am encountering is `AddNewSubscriptionFolderShortcutInheriting()` expects an object of the type `IManSubScriptionFolder` where `FindRootSubscriptionFoldersNotSubscribedTo()` returns a `IManFolders` object.

Can anyone point me in the direction of what I need to do to get an instance of the users My Matters as a IManSubscriptionFolder object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably my response will be a bit late for you, but I hope that it will help anybody else who will have the same issue.

Answering your question, in order to get an instance of other users My Matters as a IManSubscriptionFolder object you just need to loop through the collection of objFolders and cast each folder to the IManSubScriptionFolder type.

Please find below my working solution:

```
ManDMS dms = new ManDMS();
string serverName = "dms.server.com";
IManSession session = dms.Sessions.Add(serverName);
string userID = "user";
string password = "password";
session.Login(userID, password);

ManStrings dblist = new ManStrings();
dblist.Add("TargetWsDbName");

IManSubscriptionFolderSearchParameters searchParams = ndms.CreateSubscriptionFolderSearchParameters();
string folderOwner = "AnotherUser";
searchParams.Add(imFolderAttributeID.imFolderOwner, folderOwner);
IManFolders nonSubscribedRootSubscriptionFolders = session.WorkArea.SubscriptionFolder.FindRootSubscriptionFoldersNotSubscribedTo(dblist, searchParams);

foreach (var folder in nonSubscribedRootSubscriptionFolders)
{
    //another user's subscription folder
    var subscriptionFolder = folder as IManSubscriptionFolder;
    if (subscriptionFolder != null)
    {
        //Current user's subscription folder shortcuts
        var subscriptionFolderShortcuts = session.WorkArea.SubscriptionFolder.SubFolders as IManSubscriptionFolderShortcuts;
        if (subscriptionFolderShortcuts != null)
        {
            subscriptionFolderShortcuts.AddNewSubscriptionFolderShortcutInheriting(subscriptionFolder);
        }
    }
```

Please note that code from above was included for reference purpose only and it is not a production code.

Comment: Thanks, thats pretty similar to what I ended up developing.